# C++ exception handling from constructors without try/catch blocks

Tags: c++, exception, constructor, try-catch

On a school project I'm currently working on we have to write to and read from binary files.
To make my code more elegant I've opted to use serialization ctors in one of the classes, which receive an ifstream to read from the file in order to get their appropriate data.

One of our requirements is that we need to check for successful readings from the file, but aren't allowed to implement exception handling in the form of the try-catch blocks yet. So the only option I can think of is returning a boolean value if the reading wasn't successful. Problem is I have nested classes, for example the first class looks like:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(ifstream& input)
    {
      // read data from input //
      // call load method of nested class B  // 
     }

private:
   // some data // 
   B b;
};
```

And the nested class, instead of having a ctor which receives a file, will call to its load method to read the appropriate data, so B will look like this:

```
class B
{
public:
   void load(ifstream& input);

private:
    // some data // 
};
```

What would be an alternative way to handle exceptions, or what changes would you recommend making to my code so it would align with the project requirements?

Making B's load method boolean, and return false for example if the reading was bad would lead me back to the ctor of A, which I can't return a value from.

I'm coding in C++ for a couple of months now so apologies if something here seems like bad design or plain wrong - would appreciate any feedback as well. Thank you.

Comment: Move all of that reading code from the constructor to a function you have to explicitly call.

Comment: `Class` should be `class`, `Class B;` is not a declaration of a member and you are missing `;`. I fixed those

Comment: what should happen when reading from the file fails?

Comment: not sure anymore if my edit was ok. You say "nested class", so my change to make it a member might be off

Comment: The main way a constructor has to report errors is to throw an exception.  If you can't throw an exception from the constructor, it is better to avoid reading from a file (inherently error prone) in a constructor and instead do the reading in another function that can return a value instead of throwing.    An alternative is to set some object state to indicate an error condition - the problem with that is almost invariably some form of erroneous (e.g. undefined) behaviour if a member function forgets to check the error condition, and acts as if no error has occurred.

Comment: Ok, so as I understand it - by not being able to throw exceptions I should avoid the ifstream constructor altogether?

Answer (score 1):

By default, iostreams do not have exceptions enabled. And enabling exceptions on a
`std::istream` object is usually a very bad idea. So I wouldn't count on it being
active.

Change the `std::ifstream` to `std::istream`. This will make the code must more
flexibile in testing since it no longer requires a `ifstream` and you can use `std::istringstream` for testing when calling you code.

Suggest changing the API of `load` to

```cpp
   std::istream& load(std::istream& input);
```

This is in line with most other iostream operators, it just returns the `input` variable. It makes it easier for the caller to pipeline the calls.

The code in your `A::A(std::istream& input)` can after and/or before calling `b.load(input);` check for results with `good`, `eof`, `fail` and/or `bad`
on `input`. This should be enough to then decide how your `bool` should be set
to convey an appropriate failure.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot throw from constructor, you probably need then a static factory which allows to return *"error"* too.

There are proposals for `std::expected<T, Error>`, but not yet available, some library might propose equivalent.

Possible ways currently include usage of `std::optional` or (smart-)pointers:

```
class B
{
    B() = default;
public:
    static std::optional<B> load(std::istream& input)
    {
        B b;
        // read input...
        if (errorDetected) { return std::nullopt; }
        return b;
    }

private:
    // some data
};
class A
{
public:
    static load(std::istream& input)
    {
        A a;
        // read data from input
        if (errorDetected) { return std::nullopt; }

        auto b = B::load(input);
        if (!b) return std::nullopt;
        a.b = std::move(*b);

        return a;
    }

private:
   // some data
   B b;
};
```

without `std`, `optional` might be quickly implemented (there are several caveats but it might be good enough) with something like:

```
template <typename T>
class my_poor_optional
{
    T data; // required to be constructed, even when invalid contrary to real optional
    bool is_valid = false;
public:
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd add streaming operators (`operator>>` and `operator<<`) for `A` and `B` instead of having a converting constructor and a `load` member function.

Example:

```
class B {
public:
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, B& b) {
        return is >> b.b_data;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const B& b) {
        return os << b.b_data;
    }

private:
    int b_data;
};

class A {
public:
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, A& a) {
        return is >> a.a_data
                  >> a.b;             // uses B's operator>>
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A& a) {
        return os << a.a_data << ' '
                  << a.b;             // uses B's operator<<
    }

private:
    int a_data;
    B b;
};
```

You can then stream from a file and check the state of the stream to see if extraction worked or not:

```
    // ...
    A foo;

    if(input >> foo) { // input is true in boolean contexts if extraction succeeds
        std::cout << "Successfully read an A: " << foo;
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Failed reading from stream\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to take a look at [exception masks](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions) of `basic_ios` if you want to be sure that IO operations **shouldn't** throw exceptions on error.

Comment: This does not address the more serious problem of a constructor leaving an object in an invalid state if an I/O error occurs (e.g. if some members of the object are successfully read from the file, and some are left uninitialised due to an I/O error).   This type of problem can occur regardless of whether I/O operations throw or not.

Comment: By default, streams do not throw exceptions. There's no need to mess with exception masks unless you've already messed with the exception masks.